# Caching of the data of a big file in memory in java

Tags: java, algorithm, memory-management, garbage-collection, nlp

Hi I am working on Spelling Corrector project of Natural Language processing and I am supposed read data from a file whose size is <strike>6.2 MB</strike> 1 GB. While it is working fine, the problem that I am facing is that every time I run the java program I have to load the data in to the memory and it is taking same amount of time every time it is run.

Is there any way this data can cached in to the memory in java?Can any one suggest me some work around of it?

Basically what I want to know is that What is procedure of storing content of a large file in memory so that I dont have to read it again? lets say file is of GB.

Comment: If its the same file, can you produce an index of some kind & store that in a file?

Comment: You want that your data will stay in memory while your program is stopped? Please add some lines to make clear what you want. Seems that i don't understand you right.

Comment: Did you try to profile your code to see if there are any bottlenecks in e.g. parsing of the file?

Comment: Editing it to 1GB makes it a completely different question.

Comment: @NoxHarmonium Yes that is what I wanted in the first place.actually the file I have is a small one right now and but in a week or so I will merge data from the novels and other online resources. so it is bound to increase.so at that time I will have to use something efficient like cache to make sure I dont read the content again and agian. I hope this is clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see here that loading/parsing of the data from the file and creating the cache is causing you some time delay and you want to save time from doing this every time.

In this case, I would suggest you to use [EHcache](http://ehcache.org/).
The EHcache (which is ofcource open source and apache licensed) will maintain the cahce for you, prevent your application from Out of memory errors and also will save the state of the cahce to the disk.

So, on the next boot of your application, you can configure you application to directly boot from the EHcahce Data file, so in this way you will avoid parsing your file again and again.

You can still load whatever cahce you are using into memory, only difference is load it though the EHCache APIs.

Comment: If loading the file is a performance problem, I would not store it in an unpredictable weak cache. Either there is enough memory to cache the file, or there isn't. EHcache is just overkill for this problem; just ensure you start the VM with enough heap space.

Comment: Why is EHCache an overkill? I use it for caching purposes as well, because it can be stored in files as well.

Answer (score 5):

6.2 MB of data will probably be stored in the cache of your operating system as it is a relatively small amount of data and therefore shouldn't take much time at all to load. You should investigate whether it is the parsing of this data that is taking a long time and maybe cache the parsed data to a binary file for quick loading.

Answer (score 4):

6.2 MB isn't very big and unless this is taking a long time and you can't use a background thread to load the file I wouldn't worry about it.

You can use memory mapped files but these are not as simple to work with.  Memory mapped files are useful if you have between 1 GB and 1 TB of data.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to code/debug your program and it seems that reloading the resources for every changes you do takes too much time then consider [JRebel Social](https://social.jrebel.com/dashboard) (if this is a non-commercial project, or [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) if it is). It allows you to fix bugs in your code or do some changes without restarting your VM, so you get to retain the loaded data (e.g., stored in a static variable), without using any cache or even having to restart your VM. See my previous question: [Loading Resources Once in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148161/loading-resources-once-in-java). But if it's for production, and your intent is to save memory than saving load time (which in most cases is a problem limited only during startup), then EhCache or other caching libraries should be enough.